# почему сокеты в linux выкидывают null а в windows SocketException

Tags: java, сокет, чат

Есть консольный чат на сокетах. 
Если клиентская сторона отваливается, то на стороне сервера при попытке получить сообщение в linux получаем null, а в windows SocketException. Почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот неплохой [комментарий на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931811/differences-on-java-sockets-between-windows-and-linux-how-to-handle-them) 
Идея, не переводя весь текст - "разный API при работе с TCP". 
Как пример (из того же материала):
В Linux/Unix при работе с сокетами вы используете идентификатор сокета, который на самом деле является дескриптором файла (fd). Если клиент отваливается, fd закрывается операционной системой. Что вынудит на TCP уровне сделать обмен пакетами для закрытия  сокета с FIN/ACK-флагами. В случае Windows, если Вы не вызываете закрытие сокета (closesocket) (падает клиент) отправляется пакет RST.